# differential arithmetic forms

Tags: differential-geometry, arithmetic

i know a little about real differential forms and complex differential forms. Is it to possible to consider differential forms on other fields, and for what use ?

Comment: First example that comes to mind:  an algebraic equivalent is used to define and study, for instance, smooth and étale morphisms in algebraic geometry.

Comment: You can also define analytic functions on $p$-adic abelian manifolds (at least, it’s possible that it’s more general but I don’t know the exact conditions) by “line integrals” of differential forms. Locally (in the analytic topology) it’s “simply” evaluating an antiderivative of the power series of the $1$-form. See eg Coleman, Effective Chabauty for an algebraic application to give a strong bound under some conditions on the number of rational points on a curve. Not sure if that’s what you’re asking though.

Comment: Thanks for your help !! I'm going also to have a look on kähler differentials...